# Broadcast message to multiple Multiprocessing processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, simultaneous

I have a Multiprocessing application with a bunch of processes, I want the control thread to broadcast a message to multiple processes. If I used a pipe pair for each there will be a ton of pipes.

Is there a way to send one message to multiple processes at the same time?

Comment: A bunch of pipe pairs is not really a bad thing.... For organization, I would personally subclass `Process` and make the Pipe (or Queue) as an attribute in `__init__`

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends what your actual purpose is in sending the message:

- if the purpose is to share a value/values amongst the processes, you can use a `multiprocessing.Value` or a `multiprocessing.Array`
- if the purpose is to synchronise the next phase of some processing, you could use a `multiprocessing` `Barrier` or `Event`
- if you really want to do *"Pub/Sub"* of lots of messages, you would probably want to use Pub/Sub from **Redis** or **MQTT** with `mosquitto` broker.